# OSX--ikImageBrowserView scroll

Tags: macos

I want to make an image browser such as iOS album,which can show images by the date, I use a scrollview,and add some ikImageBrowserview on it,when I scroll, the ikImageBrowserview's visibleRect is change,when the visibleRect is too small,the images disappear,but i can drag the view to see them.
   Now,i want to know,how to set the size of ikimagebrowserview's contentview,or how to make an image browser such as iOS album?THX!